# Mostrar información de un solo tipo de usuario (administrador o paciente) en Datatables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

he venido hasta aca para realizar una consulta con respecto a datatables. Siendo sincero estoy comenzando con datatables, espero que puedan ayudarme con mi consulta y me puedan explicar un poco con lo que dire a continuacion:

Yo tengo una base de datos donde se guardan los datos de todos los usuarios que se van registrando en mi sistema. Tengo un tipo_usuario que es para poder manejar los roles de cada usuario (si es tipo_usuario = 1 es administrador, si es tipo_usuario = 2 es usuario normal).

En mi datatable yo llamo a la tabla usuarios para que se muestre la informacion que yo deseo, en este caso el nombre, apellido, su DNI, telefono y correo.

Hasta ahi todo esta bien, la duda esta especificamente al momento de mostrar la informacion porque yo quiero que el datatable apenas inicie, solamente me muestre la informacion de los usuarios que son tipo_usuario = 2, es decir, los datos de los usuarios que son usuarios normales sin que se muestren los administradores del sistema.

En pocas palabras, como hago para que mi datatables solamente muestre los datos de los usuarios que son tipo 2?

mi codigo esta de la siguiente forma (de manera resumida)

en mi index.php tengo el siguiente script

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){


            $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#fff"); // filas impares
            $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#dddddd"); // filas pares
            $('#mitabla').DataTable({
```

y tengo mi server_process.php de la siguiente forma (algunas cosas)

```
  <?php


    require 'conexion.php';

    /* Nombre de La Tabla */
    $sTabla = "usuarios";

    /* Array que contiene los nombres de las columnas de la tabla*/

    $aColumnas = array('nombres', 'apellidos', 'dni', 'telefono','correo');

    /* columna indexada */

    $sIndexColumn = "dni";
    // Paginacion
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".$_GET['iDisplayStart'].", ".$_GET['iDisplayLength'];
    }

//Obtener datos para mostrar SQL queries
    $sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumnas))."
    FROM   $sTabla
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
    ";
    $rResult = $mysqli->query($sQuery);

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
    $aResultFilterTotal = $rResultFilterTotal->fetch_array();
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
    SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
    FROM   $sTabla
    ";
    $rResultTotal = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
    $aResultTotal = $rResultTotal->fetch_array();
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];

    /*
        * Output
    */
    $output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
    );
```

intente creando un condicional pero no me ha funcionado. Espero puedan ayudarme y agradezco a quien lo haga de verdad.

Comment: Hola Bienvenido a [es.SO], te invito a que leas el [tour] para que entiendas como funciona esta comunidad y de paso te informes de [ask]. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Podes definir la condición que deben cumplir los registros de una tabla de la base de datos, mediante la clausula `WHERE` de `SQL`. Como ya existe la variable `$sWhere`, lo único que te falta es asignarle un valor.

```php
 /* Condición de la consulta */
 $sWhere = " WHERE tipo_usuario = 2 "

 $sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumnas))."
    FROM   $sTabla
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
    ";
    $rResult = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
```